# allow all regular users to show and read all posts in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blogs

i'm new in Laravel, and i want to upload one of the free source blogs. but unfortunately there is one small bugs in it.

when the regular users want to browse single post, the website redirecting to the login page. i want to allow all regular users to show and read all posts in Laravel.

below is 'web.php'  code I used

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('primary');
Route::get('/archive', 'WelcomeController@archive')->name('pages.archive');
Route::get('/contact', 'WelcomeController@contact')->name('pages.contact');
//Route::get('/post/{id}', 'HomeController@show')->name('posts.show');

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'TagController');
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
    Route::get('/trashed_posts', 'PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed');
    Route::get('/restore/{id}', 'PostController@restore')->name('posts.restore');
    Route::get('/users/{user}/profile', 'UserController@edit')->name('user.edit');
    Route::post('/users/{user}/profile', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'VerifyAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/users/index', 'UserController@index')->name('users.index');
    Route::post('/users/{user}/admin_role', 'UserController@make_admin')->name('users.admin_role');
    Route::post('/users/{user}/writer_role', 'UserController@make_writer')->name('users.writer_role');
});
```

and below is the relative code for 'postController'

```
public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('checkCategories')->only('create');
    }

public function show(Post $post)
    {
        $user = $post->user;
        $latestpost = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
        return view('pages.single', ['post' => $post, 'categories' => Category::all(), 'tags' => Tag::all(), 'user' => $user, 'latest' => $latestpost]);
    }
```

Please allow all regular users [Guests] to show and read all posts.

Thank you

Comment: You shoul uncomment the line that contains `Route::get('/post/{id}', 'HomeController@show')->name('posts.show');`

Comment: Change this 4th line `//Route::get('/post/{id}', 'HomeController@show')->name('posts.show');
` to `Route::get('/post/{id}', 'HomeController@show')->name('posts.show');` hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Clement , STA for your comments, I actually tried alot to solve this , I added the above route and tried to create new function in HomeController , but still same problem.

Comment: Please have a look for the source code that I used,  https://github.com/YoussefHarizi/myblog

Answer (score 0):

I Know now what was the problem, posts route was at the wrong group inside the (middleware), hence it should redirect users to the login page...

Solution:
remove below code from "Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function ()"

````
```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```
````

and paste it up before "Auth::routes();"

thanks for your time...